# A 20 year old (or more) book which starts with a spaceman burying a crew member

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've searched sci-fi book lists until blue in the face it is not from a common or well known author. The story is more of a personal drama orientated around loneliness and solitude than a multi faceted fantasy. I would like to re-read it but I've lent it out and lost it.

Comment: This is really sparse. Have a read through the checklists at '[How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)' and see if you can add anything.

Comment: What language was the book written in? How long was the book? Was it for adults or young adults? What was the setting (space, a planet, a moon)? Why were they burying this crew member? Was the crew member male or female? How big was the crew? How did they get into space? Was this futuristic sci-fi or something more realistic? Aside from burying the crewman, did they do anything else?

Comment: Probably not it, but The Halcyon Drift by Brian Stableford starts with a spaceman isolated on a planet who has to keep putting up the cross on his engineer's makeshift grave when the wind blows it off.  The wind is actually a (non-evil) entity trying to get into his mind, and he's soon rescued, but the main character's loneliness and isolation do sort of continue throughout the book (although it's also an actiony-space-opera).

Comment: If the poster gives more details and this turns out to be Lem's *Return from the Stars*, then I'm good at crystal ball guessing.